# Remove special character and number only in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do we remove numbers and special character without removing the whitespace in a string?

eg:

```
$input = "Random string with random 98 and %$% output"; 

$filtered_input = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\s]/", "", $input);
```

I have tried the above code but it is not working. I've also tried to read the php manual but I dont quite understand the content. All the example that I found online remove whitespace from the string. Can anyone show me how it can be done or suggest some good reading for me

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `trim(preg_replace("/\s*[^\s\p{L}]/", "", $input))` or `trim(preg_replace("/\s*[\d\p{P}\p{S}]+/", "", $input))`. Add `u` modifier if you need to work with Unicode text.

Comment: what result are you expecting? now it's presenting: "Random string with random  and  output"

Comment: Another solution: `trim(preg_replace("/\s*(?:(?!\s)[\W\d])+/", "", $input))`

Comment: Also see https://3v4l.org/S2LIJ. Please let know if that works for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much for your help. All of your solution works :)

Comment: @myxaxa that was just an example, I want to generate a code that contain only alphabets from a title given by the user which sometime contain numbers and special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$input = "Random string with random 98 and %$% output"; 
$filtered_input = trim(preg_replace("/\s*(?:[\d_]|[^\w\s])+/", "", $input));
echo $filtered_input;
```

Output:

```
Random string with random and output
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b5dEEb/1) and the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/S2LIJ).

**Details:**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (before a value you need to remove)
- `(?:[\d_]|[^\w\s])+` - one or more occurrences of either a digit or an underscore or any char other than word and whitespace.

The `trim` function removes any resulting leading whitespaces if any.